# Difference with JTS geometry leaving edge vertices as dashed

Tags: geometry, jts-topology-suite

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to erase water layer from the Maine Island (listed in colour red ) below .

```
public static SimpleFeatureCollection difference(SimpleFeatureCollection collA, SimpleFeatureCollection collB) {
    SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(collA.getSchema());
    List<SimpleFeature> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collA.features()) {
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
            Geometry geom = (Geometry) f.getDefaultGeometry();
            Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property(collB.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName()),
                    ff.literal(geom));
            SimpleFeatureCollection sub = collB.subCollection(filter);
            if (!sub.isEmpty()) {
                // union the geometries that overlap
                Geometry result = null;
                try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr2 = sub.features()) {

                    while (itr2.hasNext()) {
                        SimpleFeature f2 = itr2.next();
                        Geometry geom2 = (Geometry) f2.getDefaultGeometry();
                        // trying to see if performance gain work
                        // Geometry g =geom2.buffer(0);
                        if (result == null) {
                            result = geom2;
                        } else {
                            Collection<Object> s = new ArrayList<Object>();
                            // result =combineIntoOneGeometry(result, geom2) ;
                            s.add(result);
                            s.add(geom2);
                            // result = UnaryUnionOp.union(s);
                            result = CascadedPolygonUnion.union(s);
                            // result = result.union(geom2);
                        }
                    }
                    itr2.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //69.5348960 43.6447403
                if (result.isValid() && geom.isValid()) {
                    // calc difference
                    // Geometry g = OverlayNGRobust.overlay(geom, result, 3);
                    // Geometry g =EnhancedPrecisionOp.difference(geom, result);
                    Geometry g = geom.difference(result);
                    // Geometry g1 = removeHoles(g, p -> p.getArea() > 0.01);
                    builder.addAll(f.getAttributes());
                    String geomName = collA.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();
                    builder.set(geomName, g);
                    SimpleFeature fout = builder.buildFeature(null);
                    ret.add(fout);
                } else {
                    if (!result.isValid()) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid result");
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }
                    if (!geom.isValid()) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid geom");
                        System.out.println(geom);
                    }
                }

            } else {// no intersection
                ret.add(f);
            }
        }
        itr.close();
    }
    return DataUtilities.collection(ret);

}
```

But this is not removing the some of boundary polygon.

Comment: That looks more like a data problem (they don't exactly match) rather than a JTS error - it is working exactly as I would expect it to.

Comment: You might be right , it possible the source data is not correct. But with the same files , when i am using Arcgis Map Erase feature , it is working fine with maintaning the topology and all island etc. I tried the Topologya and doughlas simplifier in java , but it removed most of the island as well with tolerance set to 0.00001. So i am looking for anything which can fix this further through Java. I even tried g.buffer(0) but couldnt able to fix. So if you can suggest something, that will be very helpful. Thanks